# How to display water intake from ml as n icons cups?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display calculated amount of cups as cup icon.
 One icon = 220 ml.

Goal: 3.60 l
**Cups: 16.363636363636363**

Could anyone help me with this? I want it to be displayed as 16 icons cups.

```
.col-xl-4.mb-5
           
                p Goal: {{ waterIntake }} litres
                p Cups: {{ cupsIntake }}
```

```
waterIntake() {
      var currentWeight = this.goalWeight;
      var water = currentWeight * 0.03;
      let text = water.toFixed(2);
      return text;
    },
```

```
cupsIntake() {
        var currentWeight = this.goalWeight;
        var water = currentWeight * 30;
        let litres = water.toFixed(1);
        let cups = water / 220;
        return cups;
      },
```

Comment: I'd like it to be displayed as icons <i class="fas fa-glass-whiskey"></i>
One icon = 220 ml.

Comment: Yes, I want to display it as cup icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use v-for in range to render list of icons, but your `cupsIntake()` return value must be an integer and `cupsIntake()` must be a computed property for this to work.

```
<i v-for="cup in cupsIntake" :key="cup" class="fas fa-glass-whiskey" />
```

Add Math.round or Math.ceil (depending on your business logic) to `cupsIntake()`

```
return Math.round(cups);
```